# WooCommerce free delivery over certain amount and only for certain products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need some kind of a WordPress plugin that allows me to have 2 different product classes on WooCommerce, and for each one, I put a limit and when the customers cart went over the limit for that certain product class, the shipping cost gets free.

For example, I have books and pens in my shop
when a customer adds pens to his/her cart, the limit for free shipping will be 20$
and if he/she adds books, the limit gets to 50$
and in case they add both items the limit will be the higher one (50$)

Comment: The plugin you introduced was exactly what i wanted, thank u very much @RobyRajuOommen

Comment: @7uc1f3r it wasn't about code-writing, i wanted a plugin and thanks to Roby i found it

Comment: @MohammadAslani, you should try to search for what you want before asking questions like these on Stackoverflow, since answers to questions like these can be easily found on internet and it doesn't show any research effort. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'shipping_class_based_cost', 15, 2);

function shipping_class_based_cost($rates, $package) {


    if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX'))
        return $rates;

    $shipping_class_books = 'books';
    $shipping_class_pen = 'pen';
    $my_shipping_classes = array($shipping_class_books, $shipping_class_pen);

    $has_shipping_class_books = $has_shipping_class_pen = false;

    $shipping_class_found = false;

    // loop through cart items and checking for the specific product class
    foreach ($package['contents'] as $item) {
        $item_shipping_class = $item['data']->get_shipping_class();
        if (in_array($item_shipping_class, $my_shipping_classes)) {
            if ($shipping_class_books == $item_shipping_class)
                $has_shipping_class_books = true;
            if ($shipping_class_pen == $item_shipping_class)
                $has_shipping_class_pen = true;

            $shipping_class_found = true;
        }
    }

    if ($shipping_class_found) {

        // loop through shipping rates
        foreach ($rates as $rate_key => $rate) {

            if ($rate->method_id == 'flat_rate') {
                $cart_total = $package['cart_subtotal'];
                if ($has_shipping_class_pen && $cart_total > 20)
                    $rates[$rate_key]->cost = 0.00;

                if ($has_shipping_class_books && $cart_total > 50)
                    $rates[$rate_key]->cost = 0.00;

                $has_taxes = false;
                $taxes = [];

                // loop through the shipping taxes array
                foreach ($rates[$rate_key]->taxes as $key => $tax) {
                    if ($rates[$rate_key]->taxes[$key] > 0) {
                        $taxes[$key] = 0;
                        $has_taxes = true;
                    }
                }
                if ($has_taxes)
                    $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = $taxes;
            }
        }
    }

    return $rates;
}
```